# Flattening the Json object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to flatten a json body in the data flow in Azure Data Factory but not sure what value should go in Unroll by and unroll root field. Here is the screens shot of data preview of source.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on *Unroll by* dropdown. You will get valid value which can be Unroll. As shown in below image. You can provide only array object.

[image]

You can refer to this [video](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/videoplayer/embed/RWLX9j) as well.

**Unroll by**

Select an array to unroll. The output data will have one row per item in each array. If the unroll by array in the input row is null or empty, there will be one output row with unrolled values as null.

**Unroll root**

By default, the flatten transformation unrolls an array to the top of the hierarchy it exists in. You can optionally select an array as your unroll root. The unroll root must be an array of complex objects that either is or contains the unroll by array. If an unroll root is selected, the output data will contain at least one row per items in the unroll root. If the input row doesn't have any items in the unroll root, it will be dropped from the output data. Choosing an unroll root will always output a less than or equal number of rows than the default behavior.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten#unroll-by